# "Default" view in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController with 5 NavigationControllers, embedded in it as tabs (similar to picture 1 below). So, the question is: I want to show the table view (or any another view) as a "default" view, when the TabBarController is shown. I.e., show the view (view controller), which is not embedded in TabBarController and make any tab selected. I apologize for such explanation, better watch on picture #2 below. I'm using latest version of XCode and Swift in my project. And for interface I'm using storyboard

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 2):

You can determine which tab to select in the first (initial) viewController.

*Note: Swift 3*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
  }
```

Note that by default the first selected viewController is at 0 index (`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`)

Comment: I didn't need to determine which tab must be selected, when app loads, I needed something like VC with tabbar, where no tabs are selected

Comment: Then you can simply add a view under the tableview add five images (or buttons) in it, is that what you want?