# How to navigate view controller using UITabBar in swift?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController and 4 UITabBarItem. I want to navigate through them programmatically. I'm looking forward on how to do it.. (Swift)

Comment: What did you try to do? i.e where is your code snippet?

Comment: There are many answers about this topic, I assume [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40111462/5501940) should be useful to your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 //1, 2 or 3
```

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if loadViewAtTabIndex != -1 {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
            loadViewAtTabIndex = -1
        }
        self.pullDataFromSourceAndUpdateUI()
    }

Comment: i did add the above code what you told in the viewWillAppear method. Even though the lines are executed, the preferred tab is not shown

Comment: I don't know what is "loadViewAtTabIndex" here (maybe, it equals -1 in your case) but I'd try to put just one line in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. Also, if you update your question with code of your viewController it'd much simpler for me or others to help you.